# How to print "<20%" in BI Publisher report, when we are entering text from rich text editor

Tags: oracle11g, rtf, bi-publisher

Here data is coming as html in data model. And we used html2fo in rtf report. Result we are getting is : "2%", It is removing '<' and first character after it. Any suggestion.

Comment: What is user typing into front end? What is being stored in Databased? What is column type, and what's the query to get the data from database into XML? What's data look like in XML (Whole element)? What's the RTF selection code of that element? The more details the better.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether html2fo is compatible with this but try:

Use `&lt;` for `<`

Or `&gt;` for `>`